# Making illegal any activity

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

source: [https://www.amazon.com/Barrons-GRE-Verbal-Workbook-2nd/dp/143800379X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143800379X)

Making illegal any activity that is popular and not overtly harmful_______ a trade-off between the advantages gained and the disadvantages posed ________ a black market develops in the activity.

1. a. impugns
   b. entails
   c. abets
2. a. if
   b. unless
   c. until

Dear experts, I'm having trouble with the meaning of the sentence and the answers (entails, if) that the book mentioned. However, the book didn't explain anything.

Can anyone help me understand why did the answers make sense?

Comment: Hello Richard, as a learner I would say that means not all the popular and apparently harmful activities should be banned, so it depends on the pros and cons of the situation. If the cons overshadows the pros, we should say it is better to make the activity illegal.

Comment: @Cardinal Cardinal, what if I take until for the second blank? What is wrong then?

Comment: I think it is a sort of cause and effect relationship, I mean the advantages and disadvantages are the consequences of the black market. So, unless and until does not make sense. I mean you have to have something in the first place, and then you will be able to investigate the pros and cons of it.

Comment: It's ambiguous in the context (with the blanks unfilled) what the "advantages gained and the disadvantages posed" refer to. It could refer to making the activity illegal, it could refer to the activity itself, or it could refer to the black market. If we decide that the advantages and disadvantages refer to making the activity illegal, then "until" is a valid answer, and it means the trade-off will end when a black market develops. The "if" answer has a clearer logical meaning, but both make legitimate sentences.

Answer (score 2):

If an activity is made illegal and (without a black market) unavailable, there is no trade-off between what *might* be its dis/advantages because there *is* no activity. So the second blank can't be filled with **unless** or **until** – which leaves **if**.

We can't use **unless** or **until** because without the black market which *enables* the illegal activity, there is no relevance to a trade-off between its pros/cons. And if there was no trade-off, then **unless** and **until** are invalid concepts.

So **if** there is black market activity *then* its pros/cons become relevant. And if there is a trade-off between those pros/cons then **impugns** and **abets** can't be right, because the subject of those verbs is "making the activity illegal", whereas the cause & effect is the other way round. This leaves **entails**.

Looking at the whole sentence

> Making illegal any activity / that is popular and not overtly harmful / **entails** a trade-off / between the advantages gained and the disadvantages posed / **if** a black market develops in the activity.